# group_by two columns, then delete all but one of available rows

Tags: r, dplyr

[image]

I have what probably amounts to a very simple question, but it's been a long day and I'm banging my head against the wall.

With the above dataframe (hopefully the image shows up), I want to group_by PIT and Presence, then delete the rows that do not have check = 1. However, I want to keep all the other rows when check = 0, if they are the only row for the PIT and Presence grouping.

Maybe another picture will help. I want to end up with this, after the red rows are deleted.

[image]

Thanks.

I have tried nearly every combination of what little R-code I know: unique, distinct, select, filter, etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `filter(check == max(check))` after grouping and this would keep all 1s when 1s are present and all 0s when not:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  PIT = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 10),
  Presence = rep(c("c", "d"), times = 2, each = 5),
  check = c(0,0,1,1,0,
            0,0,0,1,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,
            1,0,0,1,0)
)

df |> 
  group_by(PIT, Presence) |> 
  filter(check == max(check))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#> # Groups:   PIT, Presence [4]
#>    PIT   Presence check
#>    <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1 a     c            1
#>  2 a     c            1
#>  3 a     d            1
#>  4 b     c            0
#>  5 b     c            0
#>  6 b     c            0
#>  7 b     c            0
#>  8 b     c            0
#>  9 b     d            1
#> 10 b     d            1
```

Do check with your data. If it doesn't suit, then consider putting a sample of your data in your question (rather than images which we can't use) and we can try out something more tailored to get it working!